# Why is Taiga afraid of dogs?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

On the Kuroko no Basuke Wikia [here](http://kurokonobasuke.wikia.com/wiki/Taiga_Kagami#Personality) under personality it says this about why Kagami Taiga is afraid of dogs which is as follows...

> When Kuroko brought Tetsuya #2 (The Dog) to training, it is revealed that Kagami is scared of dogs. This fear originates from his time in America, where he was once bitten by a dog.

However I am not sure if this information is accurate or just made up. Does anyone know what episode in Kuroko no Basuke mentions where this fear originates from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kuroko no Basuke wikia (unlike most wikias) is actually pretty good about citing its sources. The statement you quote includes a reference to chapter 74 (found in volume 9), page 9:

[image: lower-right panel from c74 p9]

The left-hand speech bubble reads:

> When I was a kid back in the U.S., I got bitten by a giant dog, so [I seriously can't deal with them]...!

I don't believe this was mentioned in the anime, though. At minimum, Kagami doesn't say anything about it in episode 14, which is when the dog is introduced in the anime.

Comment: Oh, so it was in the mangas. I haven't read them myself yet since I have only watched the anime. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is said in the anime, I haven't read the manga either but I did got that from the anime. The reason why he is so scared of dogs is because when he was young he was teasing a dog, the dog got mad and bit him. so technically it was his own fault.